# Progress Bar - Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Enquanto o processamento ocorre, a tela tem que exibir uma barra de progresso pro usuário. Qual a lógica por trás disso (Python, Tkinter)? Como fazer a barra de progresso aparecer na tela enquanto o processamento estiver acontecendo?

Comment: Você tem muitas maneiras de fazer isso: `concorrência`, `paralelismo` ou até mesmo um `loop`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para atualizar a barra de progresso, associe uma variável do tkinter nela:

```
import tkinter as t
from tkinter import ttk

root = t.Tk()

.... # codigo definindo o resto da interface ...

var_barra = t.DoubleVar()
minha_barra = ttk.Progressbar(root, variable=var_barra, maximum=30)
```

Daí é só atualizar essa variável de vez em quando, e chamar o `root.update()` pra atualizar na tela!

```
var_barra.set(k) # k é um número entre 0 e o máximo 
                 # (definido como 30 no exemplo acima)
root.update()
```

A hora e a forma correta de chamar essas funções depende do processamento que você está fazendo! Em geral pode usar o `root.after()` pra chamar uma função multiplas vezes automaticamente.